# What connectors do these power supplies use?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, connector, cables

I found a few power supplies which I need for my projects. The only problem is connecting them, I have a few sockets, which are unknown to me. I can disassemble PS of course and replace sockets yet it would be better if I could identify the socket type and find suitable connectors. Could you help me identifying them?
[image]
(Artesyn PSU-32-AC a.k.a. BML 353 206/2)

[image]
(EMERSON Energy Systems BML 231 002/1)

[image]
(Eltek SMPS 1000)

**Update**
current findings:

- Artesyn PSU-32-AC: seems to be proprietary, could not find cable's part number
- BML 231 - appears to be Powerpole 15-45 (thanks @DavideAndrea)
- Eltek SMPS: https://www.electromyne.de/Electronic-Components-Connectors---Verbinder-31-Pin-H7-F24-Eurocard-DIN-41612-Connector-Socket-H-F-Type-Federleiste-Buchse.html and https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/HARTING/09062152821?qs=gIpPgrDBK%2Fg994QU0O%252Bihw%3D%3D

Comment: "Artesyn PSU-32-AC: seems to be proprietary, could not find cable's part number" Not totally proprietary: the contacts are standard: [Extreme Power from Molex and Samtec](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=parall_blade_b2b_conn&s=EXTreme%20PowerPlus%20hybrid) (my site).

Answer (score 6):

For the Eltek SMPS 1000, found the [Eltek SMPS 1000](https://dokumen.tips/documents/eltek-smps-1000.html) user manual posted on-line. This contains details of the pin-outs of the connectors, which should allow you to identify the mating parts:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

> Eltek SMPS 1000

Those are DIN 45612 board-to-board array connectors.

- Left: Type H. Mate: [Harting 09062152854222](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/harting/09062152854222/5252232)
- Right: Type MH. Mate: [Harting 09062316821](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/harting/09062316821/4334876)

[image: Harting 09062152854222]

[image: Harting 09062316821]

{Digikey}

Answer (score 4):

The `Artesyn PSU-32-AC` is part of a Ericsson GSM system. As far as I can tell, these PSUs are connected to the Internal Distribution Module (IDM) which has the cables and plugs integrated. Here is a picture of the Ericsson BMG 980 330/1 IDM that shows the plug:

[image]

(Source: [sparepart4.com](https://sparepart4you.com/shop/rf/ericsson-idm-07bmg-980-3301/))

To me these plugs look very much proprietary and since they are integrated into the unit, I doubt that they are easily available as spare parts.

Comment: The rear of the power supply looks to have DIN connectors to plug into a backplane. [HARTING DIN 41612 15 Way 10.16mm Pitch, Straight DIN 41612 Connector, Socket](https://b2b.harting.com/ebusiness/en/DIN-Power-H015FTC1-1-NFF/09062152871222) looks like could be the mating part for one of the backplane connectors.

Comment: @ChesterGillon Sorry for confusion, basically photos posted are not of the same power supply. Like I mentioned, there are few of those. The last one is Eltek SMPS 1000, and it appears you're right - it's a variation of DIN 41612. Thanks for hint

Comment: And regarding PSU-32-AC thanks as well, looks like this PSU will be torn apart and have connector replaced

Comment: @seeker To avoid further confusion can you edit the question to indicate which photo is from which PSU, and ideally give the part number for each of the PSUs.

Answer (score 4):

> EMERSON Energy Systems BML 231 002/1

Those are Anderson Power - Powerpole connectors.

https://www.andersonpower.com/us/en/resources/PowerPoleResourcesPage.html

Measure the width of each pole to determine which size Powerpole they are.

- 8.4 mm: Powerpole 15-45
- 17 mm: Powerpole 75
- 22.2 mm: Powerpole 120
- 30 mm: Powerpole 180

[image: Powerpole 15-45]

Powerpole 15-45 {My picture}

Comment: They might not be Powerpoles; there's a very similar-looking (might be compatible?) connector series made by TE, too.

Comment: "might be compatible?" - yes: they are knock-offs.